# Login Form for Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I've been playing around with Angular Material and been reading through the documentation but I can't seem to figure out how to design the layout I have in mind. Essentially I want a form in which all the elements are aligned in a column and of an equal width. I'd also like all elements or the item that holds them all to have a max width of 500px, for example. And it should also be centered both vertically and horizontally on screen. Is there any way to achieve this in Angular Material?

[image]

Comment: You want something like this screenshot above using angular1 and material1 ?

Comment: @Nehal Yes I want something like this, only allowing the max-width and centered on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what are you trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/hd1by95r/59/

**HTML:**

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-fill class="outer">
  <div layout="column" class="wrapper" flex>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Placeholder</label>
      <input>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Placeholder</label>
      <input>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" flex>
      Primary
    </md-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.outer {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Can you explain the use of flex and layout-fill?

Comment: Yes. `layout-fill` fills parent `with` and `height`, and `flex` defines how the element will adjust its size with respect to its parent

Comment: Yes, but in which direction does `flex` operate? In the direction of the `layout` attribute in the parent? What would happen after removing `flex` from the button, for example?

Comment: *"Yes, but in which direction does `flex` operate? In the direction of the `layout` attribute in the parent?"* Yes, if the parent is `layout="column"` and the child is `flex`, the child will take **maximum height** as he can, and vise versa, if the parent is `layout="row"` and the child is `flex`, the child will take **maximum width** as he can. *"What would happen after removing flex from the button, for example?"* Nothing, `flex` on button doesn't needed really

Comment: Without the padding or `layout-margin` or `layout-padding` why does the login form seem to extend past the width of the page? There's a scrollbar that appears. Don't `flex` elements take up 100% of the width by default, not 100% and a few pixels?